# dev_appserver.py slow start

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

After some time I needed to do changes on GAE Python (2.7) First Generation app, but when I develop and run locally, it's basically nonusable due to a very slow start.
These are printed logs:

```
INFO     2019-10-18 07:56:35,533 devappserver2.py:278] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2019-10-18 07:56:35,595 api_server.py:275] Starting API server at: http://localhost:36159
INFO     2019-10-18 07:56:35,599 dispatcher.py:270] Starting module "default" running at: http://127.0.0.1:8080
INFO     2019-10-18 07:56:35,600 admin_server.py:152] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2019-10-18 08:01:01,644 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 28496
```

What I notice that the last line (instance.py) is printed after ~5 minutes and only after that app responds to requests, not before. Interesting that the admin server (localhost:8000) is available right away. Of course, when I do some code change it automatically reloads and it repeats again.

Things I tried/found out:

- it behaves like that on my all GAE projects Python First Gen.
- tried to create a bare minimal version (webapp2 with one URL), clean virtualenv, still the same behavior
- tried to reinstall Google Cloud SDK. delete the whole google-cloud-sdk folder and install again, no changes
- tried to install older version of Cloud SDK
- used clean VM and it works ok!!!, so it looks like there could be something wrong with my system (outside of SDK), but I'm not sure what.

It's interesting that the pause between the last two log lines is always about 5 minutes, not sure why exactly that time.

Python 2.7.14
OS: OpenSuse Leap 15.0

I'm running out of ideas so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know why it is described as running at `http://127.0.0.1:8080` instead of `http://localhost:8080`?  I realize they point to the same place, but I get the latter instead of the former so it seems there is something different about your setup.

Comment: I had it setup like that in PyCharm config (127.0.0.1 instead of localhost). I changed to localhost but still the same. note: when I run outside of PyCharm, it's still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this accidentally.
I wanted to run Jupyter notebook, but I got the error:

```
error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

after debugging in /tornado/netutil.py, I noticed that it tries to work with IP 192.168.1.50 which I wasn't sure where did that come from, (probably I set it since I was playing with my home network some time ago), but when I deleted it from /etc/hosts, Jupyter, as well as GAE, works ok.

What a coincidence :)